# Array out of range when calculate index

Tags: c++, arrays, undefined-behavior

I got a problem when one of my friends solving a problem on online judge.

He write case 1 (example) got a worng answer and got an accept by case 2.

```
int a[4];
a[ 2+6-5 ];  //undefined behavior? case 1
a[ 2+(6-5) ];//ok  case 2
```

Accroding to C++ std §5.7.5

```
if a[ 2+6-5 ] == *( a + 2+6-5 ); //ub
if a[ 2+6-5 ] == *( a +(2+6-5)); //not ub
```

How should I explain case 1?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, since both cases are the same: `(2+6)-5 == 3 == 2+(6-5)`. Can you use these in an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the difference you think you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`E1[E2]` is equivalent to `*((E1)+(E2))`, so in the first case `(2+6-5)` will be calculated first. Therefore there will be no problem.

Quote from [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.2.1 Subscripting

> The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))

Comment: Is it possible to calculate like `1+ INT_MAX - (INT_MAX-1) `cause the problem?

Comment: @Sylveon That has very little to do with anything you mention in your question. Please update your question to show a full example which demonstrates the difference you see.

Comment: @Sylveon I got [warnings](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rfxFVoWxz3oMd6Ot) for the expression, so I guess it will cause some problems.

Comment: @BoBTFish Because that is not my code, I need to get my friend's permit

Comment: @Sylveon We don't need to see his full code, just a small example demonstrating the problem.